# PHP: Splitting a string and printing

Tags: php, string, explode

I have server output that looks like this
`PLAYER_ENTERED name ipaddress username`

If the string contains PLAYER_ENTERED there will always be 3 spaces within the string separating it (how can this be modified so it does this too?). I would like to print out only the ipaddress and username (last 2 sections).
How can this be done?

This is code that prints out the whole thing:

```
$q = $_REQUEST["ipladder"];
$f = fopen("ladderlog.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE)
{
    if (strstr($line, $q)) 
    {
        print "<li>$line"; 
    }
```

I imagine this using explode() but I've given up trying since I hardily know how to code php.

**Desired Output**
username ipaddress

Comment: Please provide an example of what it should look like, both normal and abbreviated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$q = $_REQUEST["ipladder"];
$f = fopen("ladderlog.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE)
{
    if (strstr($line, $q)) 
    {
        $data = explode(" ", $line); // split using the space into an array
                                     // array index 0 = PLAYER_ENTERED
        print "IP:" . $data[1];      // array index 1 = IP
        print "Name: " . $data[2];   // array index 2 = name
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Follow up question if you don't mind, but how would I check for duplicates, like have 2 instances of the same name and IP

Comment: Several different ways to go about it. That's another whole new question, but here is a place to start.http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php , http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
  <?
  $str = "PLAYER_ENTERED name 108.21.131.56 username";
    if ( preg_match( "~^(.+)\s+(.+)\s+([\d\.]+)\s+(.+)$~msi", $str, $vv ))
         echo $vv[3] .  " and " .$vv[4] ;
    else "N/A";
 ?>
```

IMHO Perl regexp - is the right Way to parse strings ...

Comment: Kevin, this is example ... it is not related on _any_ name or ip :)
Change string ... to see difference, also not related on number of spaces.

"~^(.+)\s+(.+)\s+([\d\.]+)\s+(.+)$~msi"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr()`to check if the first 14 characters of `$line` equals PLAYER_ENTERED and then you use `list()` and `explode()` to extract the data from the line.

```
$q = $_REQUEST["ipladder"];
$f = fopen("ladderlog.txt", "r");
while(($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE)
{
    if(substr($line, 0, 14) == 'PLAYER_ENTERED'){
        list($event, $name, $ip, $username) = explode($string); // here they come!

        echo 'Name: ' . $name . ', ip: ' . $ip . ', username: ' . $username;
    }
}
```

Comment: My mistake, please try again :)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
$tokens = explode(' ', $line);
if (count($tokens) == 4 && $tokens[2] == $q) {
    printf('IP: %s Username: %s', $tokens[2], $tokens[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = 'PLAYER_ENTERED name 108.21.131.56 username';

$data = explode(" ", $str )

print_r($data)

?>
```